# SSH public key login fails without pattern

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm running a bunch of servers with Ubuntu 14.04.1 (sun,hyperion,...) all of which use public keys (OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 on all machines) for rsync without problems. Almost all...

One connection fails without any changes in the configs or keys. Then I'll try to re-add the keys, check for ECDSA, reboot/restart ssh and it works again. Or it doesn't. In this case I just wait a random amount of time (1h up to 3 months) an do the same. This time it fixes the problem - for a while.

The relevant parts of a ssh -vvv diff:

*Successful connection*

```
debug1: Host 'hyperion.internal' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/bar/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f..),
debug2: key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 95:...
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 95:...
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to hyperion.internal ([172.16.0.10]:22).
```

*Failed connection*

```
debug1: Host 'hyperion.internal' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/bar/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f..),
debug2: key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/bar/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/bar/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bar/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/bar/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Things that I've checked several times:

- permissions for .ssh/ and id_rsa on all machines
- that I'm using the right keys
- that `ssh-copy-id -i /home/bar/.ssh/id_rsa europa@hyperion.internal` copies the right keys to tight authorized_hosts file

What didn't really help but added to the vodoo/heisenbug effect:

- rebooting the machines
- restarting the ssh service
- fiddling with global ssh options

I've pasted the full logs with some redacted info at pastebin: [wall of log](http://pastebin.com/E60ZgxLA)

Comment: Can you paste the output from the ssh log? /var/log/auth.log on failed connections